# Создание аккаунта пользователя

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть чат на php. Справа есть блок со всеми пользователями. Мне нужно при нажатии на любого из них переходить на его профиль. Вопрос в том как это реализовать, чтобы профиль сам создавался каждый раз? 
Вот код логина:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';
include 'all_users.php';
    if (isset($_POST['email-e']) && isset($_POST['password-pass'])) { 
    $email_e = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['email-e']);
    $password_pass = md5(md5($_POST['password-pass']));

    $query = "SELECT id, email, password FROM users_data 
              WHERE email = '$email_e' AND password = '$password_pass'";
    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['email-e'] = $row['email'];
  }
    else {
        echo 'User was not found!';
      header("Location: login.html"); 
    }
  }
    if (isset($_SESSION['email-e'])){
     header("Location: chat.php");
  } 
?>
```

Вот код чата:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['exit'])) {
     //unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
     session_destroy();
     header("Location: login.html");
     exit;
 }

include 'db_chat.php';
// header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//echo trim($_SESSION['email-e'])." <br />"."Вы авторизованы <br />";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Chat</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Chat</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
 input{font:12px arial} a{color:#00f;text-decoration:none} a:hover{text-decoration:underline} #wrapper,#loginform{margin:0 auto;padding-bottom:25px;background:#ebf4fb;width:504px;border:1px solid #acd8f0}#loginform{padding-top:18px}#loginform p{margin:5px} #chatbox{text-align:left;margin:0 auto;margin-bottom:25px;padding:10px;background:#fff;height:270px;width:430px;border:1px solid #acd8f0;overflow:auto} #usermsg{width:380px;height:50px;border:1px solid #acd8f0;border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px}#submitmsg{width:70px;height:53px;border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;cursor:pointer}.error{color:#f00} #menu{padding:12.5px 25px 12.5px 25px} .welcome{float:left} .logout{float:right} .msgln{margin:0 0 2px 0}.profile{position:absolute;right:100px;top:10px;width:250px;height:450px;border:1px solid black;border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;box-shadow:2px 2px 2px 2px; overflow: scroll;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome" style="font-family: 'Lobster', cursive; font-size:1.1em;">Welcome, <?php echo trim($_SESSION['email-e'])?><b></b></p>
        <form  name="message" action="" method="post">
        <p class="logout" name="logout">
            <button name="exit" id="exit" href="login.php" style="cursor:pointer; border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px; color:red;">Exit Chat</button>
        </p>
        </form>   
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="chatbox">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitmsg'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['usermsg']) && is_string($_POST['usermsg'])) {

        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $username = $_SESSION['email-e'];
        $time =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $usermsg = trim($_POST['usermsg']);

        $sql_chat ="INSERT INTO users_chat (usermsg,user_id,time) 
                    VALUES('{$usermsg}','{$user_id}','{$time}')";

        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli_chat,$sql_chat);
    } 
}
        $query_chat = "SELECT * FROM users_chat 
                        INNER JOIN users_data 
                        ON users_chat.user_id = users_data.id";
        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli_chat,$query_chat);

        while($row_chat = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

            $user_id = $row_chat['user_id'];
            print '<div>';

            echo  'Email:'.$row_chat['email'].'<br>';
            print 'Time:'.' '.$row_chat['time'].'<br>';
            print htmlspecialchars($row_chat['usermsg']).'<br><br>';
            print '</div>';
        }        
?>
</div>
<form  name="message" action=""     method="post">
<input name="usermsg" type="text"   id="usermsg" style="margin-left:25px;">
<input name="submitmsg" type="submit" id="submitmsg" value="Send" style="cursor:pointer; color:green;"/><br>
<div class="profile">
<?php
include 'db.php';
  $query_chat = "SELECT email FROM users_data";
        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query_chat);
        while($row_chat = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
           echo 'Email:'.$row_chat['email'].'<br>';
        }        
?>
</div>
</form>    
</div>
<form>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

БД работает. Все подключается и вводится.

Comment: А с текущим кодом этого не получается?

Comment: @u_mulder получилось их вывести, теперь вопрос в другом. посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Ссылка вида `profile.php?uid=`. На этой странице извлекаете из запроса `uid` и ищете пользователя с таким ИД.

Comment: @u_mulder можете показать на моем примере?

Comment: Показать __что__?

Comment: @u_mulder пример кода

Comment: Кода который делает что?

Comment: @u_mulder который создает профиль с конкретным id

Comment: Не создается никаких профилей. Есть страница которая открывает профиль с конкретным id. Если вам сложно что-то сделать - разбейте задачу на мелкие задачи и делайте по одной.